# How to set formData for boolean in Axios post request

Tags: api, vue.js, axios

I'm trying send a post request using axios to my backend but I can't send the boolean "isActive" for some reason. Is there a way to do this?

```js
async submit() {
    const isValid = await this.$validator.validateAll()
    if (isValid && !this.submitting) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.set("city", this.formData.city)
        formData.set("state", this.formData.state)
        formData.set("county", this.formData.county)
        formData.set("isActive", true) // <- NOT ACCEPTING THIS VALUE

        axios.post("/api/v1/team/createTeam", formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
            .then(res => {
                if (res.status === 200) {
                    this.submitting = true
                    this.cancelModal()
                } else {
                    console.log(res.data.code);
                }
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) can only contain string values. Setting a Boolean `true` would result in `"true"` for the value. The backend would have to convert that string to a Boolean.

Also, your header should not be `application/json` (intended for JSON payloads). If sending `FormData` as the payload, the header should be `multipart/form-data`:

```js
axios.post("/api/v1/team/createTeam", formData, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
  }
})
```

If your backend is actually expecting JSON, then you can't send `FormData`. Switch to a JavaScript object instead (which does accept Booleans):

```js
const payload = {
  city: this.formData.city,
  state: this.formData.state,
  county: this.formData.county,
  isActive: true,
}

axios.post("/api/v1/team/createTeam", payload, {
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
```